# Elasticsearch query greater than date

Tags: elasticsearch

I create an index and it save two date (D1, D2) for something, after that I want to query this monent is it between D1 and D2, so I query :

```
startdate <= "2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z" AND endate>= "2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z"
```

It successful return the data as I want, so I try to do the same things in Dev tools again with:

```
GET i_want_get_date/_search
{
  "query":{
    "query_string":{
      "query":"startdate<= \"2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z\" AND enddate>= \"2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z\""
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is:

**it cannot search any result back, the query cannot compare the date using this method**

Any suggestion? Thanks!

============================================================

Thanks **Val** answer the question, I using a very slimier query to do the same function, I change a little bit query syntax to make it works:

```
GET i_want_get_date/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startdate":{
              "lte":"2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "enddate":{
              "gte":"2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use range query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to use two [`range` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) instead

```
GET i_want_get_date/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startdate": {
              "gte": "2019-08-21T03:55:47.165Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "enddate": {
              "lt": "2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @VaI Thanks for answer the question, base on your suggestion I find the way to query it !

Answer (score 2):

This is the query that worked for me to select dates after based on a specific field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "_kuzzle_info.createdAt": {
              "gte": "2023-01-09T13:29:27.537+00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`_kuzzle_info.createdAt` is the field with the date

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in your answer, the elastic fields should come before the **gte** or **lte**

```
{
   "range": {
         "**startdate**": {
              "**lte**": "2019-08-22T03:55:47.165Z"
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If nested fields, then below query will work. Make sure the schedule data type is 'date'

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "trans",
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "trans.schedule": {
                "lte": "2023-03-23T00:35:45"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```